# Using Javascript or CSS, is there anyway to select elements that have css style overflow: hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm having some problem with my code, the last error is replace only some html elements have *overflow: hidden;* to *overflow: none;*, i can use javascript or css to do it, but i don't know how at this time. Please help me!

**Is there anyway to select elements that have css style** *overflow: hidden;* **in javascript or css?**

**UPDATE 2: (everything came ok!)**

Thanks **Pranav C Balan**, **Michael_B** have gave some awesome answers.

```js
var ele = $('.selector').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('overflow') == 'hidden';
})

ele.css('color', 'red');
```

```css
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=selector>1</div>
<div class="selector overflow">2</div>
<div class=selector style="overflow:hidden">3</div>
<div class=selector>1</div>
<div class="selector overflow">4</div>
<div class=selector>5</div>
```

Comment: What do you **REALLY** want?

Comment: If the `overflow: hidden` is declared inline in the HTML element, you can target the `style` attribute and make the match using attribute selectors.

Comment: i'm so sorry, i mention what i want in the question title, and i bold it up in my question.

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 But do you want to select them where? In CSS? jQuery? Plain Javascript?

Comment: When replacing `overflow: hidden` just remember there's no such thing as `overflow: none`. See [MDN `overflow` definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) for permitted values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** for that

```js
var ele = $('.selector').filter(function() {
  return $(this).css('overflow') == 'hidden';
})

ele.css('color', 'red');
```

```css
.overflow {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=selector>1</div>
<div class="selector overflow">2</div>
<div class=selector style="overflow:hidden">3</div>
<div class=selector>1</div>
<div class="selector overflow">4</div>
<div class=selector>5</div>
```

Comment: What about stylesheets?

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 : glad to help :)

Comment: What I meant with my question is: What if a style was set using a stylesheet?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It will still work. `.css()` return the current value. Set by files or inline.

Comment: The comment was for your older version, that used the `.style` attribute. You can mark them as obsolete

Comment: @Pranav C Balan thank you so much, but could you explain me why the code of my **UPDATE** section in the question is not work? I'm using style in html, not in a css files. Thanks for your advanced helping. If could not, that's ok, because your answer still solved my question. ^^

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 : in the updated question , you are using selector `$('.selector')`..... It will only filter element  which have that class...

Comment: update html as , `<div class=selector>1</div>
<div class="selector selector2">2</div>
<div class="selector selector2">3</div>
<div class=selector>4</div>`

Comment: ahhh, i'm sorry, i'm too bad. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS only, if the `overflow: hidden` is declared in the HTML element (i.e., inline), you can target the `style` attribute and make the match using [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

HTML

```
<div class="..." id="..." style="overflow: hidden;"> ... </div>
```

CSS

```
div[style*="overflow:hidden"], div[style*="overflow: hidden"] { ... }
```

The [asterisk `*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) tells CSS to match a `div` with a `style` attribute that *contains the substring "overflow:hidden" or "overflow: hidden"*.

Comment: The only problem with that is that not only the property `overflow` has the value `hidden`. Also, it will not catch overflow set in the CSS files.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, I revised the code (was hoping to keep it simple ;-) Also, as I prefaced in my answer, this solution applies only when the CSS is inline.